Is my yellow same as your yellow?
Are there any current tests that can check whether the colours we see are consistent with someone else? For example:

Person A and Person B are born at the same time, and both have normal vision
Person A sees yellow as "normal" yellow, while Person B perceives yellow like A's Red
Both A and B grow up learning about colours in the same school

After they grow up, both are shown a Banana; both say it is a "Yellow" colour, even though A and B do not perceive "Yellow" similarly.
I thought of some tests, like describing yellow as a pale/bright colour, but it isn't concrete!

Ultimately these are all just pigments of our imagination.

Genes for color perception vary, and there are things like colorblindness. So, no. Land mammals do not see in color (so thier coats tend to be shades of brown). Primates and humans see color and have less good night vision. Birds, fish and reptiles see in color and have basically no night vision, and they have colorful skin, scales and feathers.

Early black and white films had poor red sensitivity, so they made people's skin tones look odd. Then panchromatic films were created. Infrared film detects light invisible to our eyes, although some animals have a bit of IR perception. Some insects can see ultraviolet light. That's why they are drawn to fluorescent lamps at light.

People with colorblindness can see two colors as basically the same shade of grey. People with red-green colorblindness have trouble telling the red stoplight from the green, they have to remember that green is at the bottom (or right I think, for horizontal lights). People with yellow-blue colorblindness see them as equal shades of gray. You can't get them to reliably tell you which is which, so there is no fact of the matter how it looks to them similar to you. Dogs can't distinguish colors well either. If you can't train for an effect, it isn't there.

There are no tests and there never will be because the idea of comparing "my color" to "yours" is nonsensical once you think it through. Even if you could somehow get into somebody else's mind while still remaining yourself you still won't be able to tell if their yellow is your yellow because you still will not be them. The best you can tell is whether your and their yellow is in the same relation to something else you also agree on a name for. For example, tritanopes confuse what we call yellow with what we call violet, but it tells us nothing as to how their seeing of them compares to ours.

@NoahSchweber Sir, i wish i could upvote twice

@ScottRowe That was a whole answer spread across 3 comments.

@JedSchaaf yes, but it wouldn't address the question directly, it is to undermine the premise. For example, pigeons have 4 color receptors instead of the usual 3, they are 'tetrachromats', and they see many more colors than other animals. So is your yellow any one of their yellows? I think it is better to undermine the premises of most arguments, because it more directly takes them out of circulation, and the less stuff floating around out there the better. We can think more clearly with fewer dangling wrong ideas.

it has been proven scientifically that they are the same. Not a question for a philosophy forum

Actually, there is a simple test you can do yourself. If you look at a bright color with only the left, and then only the right eye, does it look the same? There are people for which they are slightly, but noticeably different. Same individual having a differing experience. While the difference is only gradual, there is nothing fundamentally different from above scenario.

@CaptainEmacs yes, I have that experience. I think it would happen for most anyone under some conditions, but I didn't mention it because I had already made enough comments to the effect of: "these things can be verified to differ, but this thing is locked in your head and can never be compared to anything else." Maybe the secret number inside credit card chips is actually the same for everyone?

I tried blinding you with science but no response.

@ScottRowe Ok. I mean the standard approach in math is, if, for all you do with an object, it behaves equivalently under all circumstances, it is effectively the same object. Qualia are a strange thing that attribute another, additional, identity to the "self". I suspect that much has to do with the memory of all experiences. This cannot be reproduced; not even in principle, because of the no-cloning theorem of quantum mechanics (no, I was not seeking a way to squeeze quantum theory into consciousness, in fact I used to be unconvinced of these attempts, but changed my mind ;-)

@CaptainEmacs right, if it is yellow like a duck, it is probably a duck.

@ScottRowe It has to have the whole array of properties. If only a part of them, it might be a bird, or merely a bathroom toy.

Color perception defects come on a spectrum (https://www.nei.nih.gov/learn-about-eye-health/eye-conditions-and-diseases/color-blindness) "Symptoms of color vision deficiency are often so mild that they’re hard to notice. That’s why many people with color vision deficiency don’t know they have it. And people usually adjust to differences in how they see color."  So there are plenty of people who see colors differently from one another, even people that have not been formally diagnosed as colorblind.

This is a fairly well-developed area of philosophical literature called the Knowledge Argument for Qualia. The general way this argument is constructed today comes from Frank Jackson's 1982 paper, though the general question does pre-date this. The idea is something like this:
Imagine a person, Mary, who has never seen the colour yellow because she has grown up in a grayscale room. However, Mary is a vision scientist and has read all the information there is to read, current or potential, about the colour yellow. She knows all possible 'physical facts' about yellow. One day, Mary leaves the room and goes outside and sees a yellow daffodil for the first time. Has she learned something new about the colour yellow?
There are two options here:

Yes, she has learned something new. There are non-physical facts about yellow, these are the qualia, the sensation or experience of seeing the colour, i.e. 'what it is like' to see a colour. It cannot be communicated through language.
No, she has not learned anything new. The only facts are physical facts.

This is the same question as yours because if she has learned something new, then there is something about seeing 'yellow' that we cannot communicate through language and therefore there is no way to know if two people see the same colour when they point at a 'yellow' thing. If she has not learned something new, then we can say that we could communicate the experience. Of course, that doesn't mean we have the detail or the language to be able to do it now, but the idea is that at some point our science and technical terminology will develop to the point where these facts could be communicated.
Some interesting caveats:

If you think she has learned something new, then there is a lot of consequences about the nature of consciousness and the communication of human experience. The link on 'what it is like' and this section on Access/What It Is Like Consciousnessare a good place to start on this.
One way to conceptualise the idea that she has learned something new is to think that at some point we might be able to communicate enough information for her to imagine yellow without seeing it. That would be a pretty strong indicator that we are all seeing the same colour (assuming we could reliably transmit this information).

So, the short answer is: no, we do not have a concrete answer to this question. There are no clear tests available.

I would say that about 99% of human experience is not expressible in words. So, seeing is believing (and knowing) in a way that reading is not. Would you have surgery from a surgeon who had only read books and never performed an operation? Fly in a plane with a pilot who had never flown? Is an author of books about basketball just as good at basketball as a professional athlete?

I think there's two points in response here:

The problem specifically deals with 'potential knowledge', so the idea that one day we might be able to communicate these ideas even if we don't have the language and technical ability for it right now
We can't discount the fact that we often believe that a good book on surgery is written by a surgeon, a good book on basketball is written by a player. Doing the thing seems to generally give them more information, not necessarily non-communicable information.


Yes. But people can know things in ways they cannot verbalize. I can throw and catch a ball, so my brain must know a lot of physics, but that is useless to me for passing an exam. Conversely, I could be great at solving physics equations and not be able to throw or catch to save my life. Dogs can catch balls and frisbees. Bears can learn to ride a bicycle, which involves solving differential equations in real time. Smarter than the average bear?

@ScottRowe I think you'd have to make a stronger claim than that. You have to justify the claim that not only can you not verbalize it here and now, you can necessarily not verbalize it.
Take the physics for example. You can verbalize the physics in principle, maybe just not in practice. You have to show that there exists knowledge that in principle is impossible to verbalise.

Verbalize how an orange tastes so that I taste it too.

@ScottRowe I think we're talking past each other here. The burden is on the person who believes in qualia to show that this information is necessarily impossible to communicate. Whether or not I can do it, or anyone alive today can do it, is not the point. The point is whether it will ever be possible to do it.
I can't solve the Reimann Hypothesis but that doesn't mean it's impossible to solve.

Ok. For some reason I am thinking of Helen Keller. I was mystified by her when I was a child, until I learned that she actually could see and hear normally until age 2, when an illness took those senses from her. If she had never been able to see and hear, could anyone have ever been able to communicate with her? I think not.

While this is an interesting answer, I don't think it really addresses the question of whether my yellow and yours are the same.

@Jack-Aidley — The answer addresses the question presented at the beginning of the post, namely “Are there any current tests that can check whether the colours we see are consistent with someone else?”

This experiment could potentially be done in the future on people colorblind from birth who might be able to receive gene therapy to enable them to see color.

Yes. A counter-experiment of sorts has already been done when people have a stroke that damages the V4 area of visual perception: their experience of color is completely disrupted. They themselves can report and be tested to show profound changes of color and texture sensation. So, yes.

I don't think they are the same question at all. The answer to one can be yes or no, and the answer to the other could still be yes or no.

Your yellow is functionally the same as my yellow (assuming normal colour vision).
Take any two colours, and create a smooth transition between them, like these (from here):

And those smooth transitions will appear smooth to you, me, and everyone else. Not just for this set of gradients but for every gradient you can make. What this means is that the observable differences between colours are the same, and they're the same for every colour. In other the words the contrast between different colours are the same. This table of colour contrasts (from here):

also applies to you, me, and everyone else. Which means that the appearance to me and the appearance of colour to you share all important qualities.
Does that mean that they appear to you in an identical way? Maybe not, although I have no idea how it works if they didn't, but it does mean that any differences in how we see colours have no observable differences. Without this important fact, colour-blindness tests wouldn't work.

There a few caveats:

Obviously, colour blind people have different colour perception.
As you age, the lens of your eye yellows, shifting your perception of colour.
Colour is to a large extent constructed by your brain. What you see isn't a direct representation of the world in front of you, your brain tries to compensate for the ambient lighting, etc. and show you what colour things are rather than the colour of light transmitted to your brain. This is the basis of many optical illusions, including that famous blue/black yellow/gold dress photo.
There is some biological variation in the response curves of your photo-receptors, depending on which versions of the genes coding for your three colour receptors you carry. This may produce small differences in colour perception.


"assuming normal colour vision" is a pretty big assumption. The answer is good and complete, but the whole basis for the question amounts to: "you are normal if you are normal", and so few people are.

My question was more directed towards whether there are any tests to determine the perception of colours and less towards whether differing perceptions of colours affect people's daily lives.

@ScottRowe: Normal colour vision as in "not colour blind".

@MysticMickey Yes, I'm talking about your perception. Your perception of colours is in every functional way the same as mine. It might be that there is a way of you having a functionally identical perception and see something different but I doubt it.

Yes, we don't have a way to verify that your yellow is like mine, but you must know that I supposed at the fist place that you have a yellow sensation because I utilized the principal of analogy when I compared my body to yours to deduce that you have a mental life like me. Thus, doubting that your yellow is like mine implies the doubt in the efficiency of this principle That I relied on to believe that your have a mental life!

It is a good first assumption. I have two ears, but some hearing loss in one. So I have a built-in demonstration that human perceptions vary: just cover one ear or the other. My eyes aren't exactly the same either. Things feel different with my two hands... Bilateral symmetry isn't perfect. People say that the hemispheres of our brains work differently.

Yes, I get it, I'm myself a color-blind person. what I'm saying is that we need a principle that allows us to "expand" our knowledge, that gives us the possibility to reach the minds of people and animals. The sole tool we have for that = using physical similarities as an indicator of psychological similarities between us and the others. Yes, you can restrict the use of this tool in certain circumstances, but the restriction shouldn't be done without a scientific reason. the idea is that the perception of two human beings of red is similar by default unless we have a reason to doubt it.

I know that my talk seems pragmatical and doesn't have any epistemological value, but we don't have a choice, we cannot live a life without having conviction about other people's minds, it seems then that the use of analogies is a necessity in practical life (which is the real life).

A more pragmatic view would be that it doesn't matter if the perception of red is equivalent or not, it can still be of use. Or even just that humans are persistent in trying to use things that are so poorly defined it would seem impossible for them to be of use, yet here we are.

@user3067860 I pity someone whose experience of quiet is like a Who concert, but they never seem to complain about it.

Yes and No. Yellow is a word, describing an optical aggregation. The variations are limitless. We agree on something based on experience or measurement: both are subjective and/or inaccurate/approximation. Reality (as we perceive it) is an intellectual construct.

This is the bottom line underneath Philosophy, and it would be nice if more people recognized it and started from there. Buddhism and Nonduality start there. Actually, science starts there too. Don't they teach this in school?

Short answer, "yellow" is objective, and is a specific wavelength (range) of light.

The triangle is yellow...

It is how your eye and brain got trained to associate a specific wavelength of light to a "perceived colour" in your mind...

If your eyesight "saw" blue as yellow, and yellow as blue...
... it would still get "trained" to call the yellow triangle above, "YELLOW".
Yellow is objective.
If you are blind, there is no yellow.  If you are colourblind, that can mess with whether you see some colours or do not see some colours.
But when it comes to naming what you see... the "what you see" came first, but the "what to call it" came from taught association.
So you can know that if you see "yellow" in nature... you are seeing the same "yellow" that you learned is in the triangle.
And the "yellow" in the triangle, matches "yellow" in the electromagnetic spectrum.
And you can know that when you see a baby chick, and it is yellow, and ev eryone calls it yellow, and it matches the colour in the triangle... you have a "correct common perception of yellow".  You relate the "right colour" in nature, to the colour we call "yellow".
The "What yellow is?" is a specifically defined and answerable question... answerable by presentation...
"Yellow absolutely is this..."

What you see is what "we" call "yellow".  Fact.

Enlightenment edit.  There seems to be confusion.
Fact:  Yellow is yellow.  Wavelength range x-to-y equals yellow.  By definition.
Into the eyeball comes light.  Light of various wavelengths.
When light of the yellow range (x-to-y) comes into the eye, the brain sees this range of frequencies... and thinks...

"HMMmmm... I wonder what I am supposed to call this range x-to-y that I am seeing and can discern from the other wavelengths... I will ask my mom, or my teacher, or my friends, or look it up on the internet, or read the instructions on my Fischer-Price Colour Teaching Toy."

All of them agree.  When that wavelength range x-to-y is detected... when one sees THIS:

We call it yellow.
There is no mystery about whether the person sees that wavelength, can discern that wavelength... they can tell us.  They can point to yellow.  Prove they see "yellow".
And we know exactly what "yellow" is.  Remember?  Fact.  Not mystery.  Because we can show it, compare it, agree or disagree.  Pick it out of a line-up.  Distinguish it by visual recognition and memory comparison... comparison to that which we saw when we were training our brains to "label what we were seeing".
If we did not see "yellow", we would not be able to discern yellow.  Would not be able to point at "yellow" when yellow sits beside non-yellow.
An individual that fails to see some colours... might not see "yellow" in colour and might see it in shades of grey.  We know, because there can be shades of grey of different colours that they wont be able to discern between.
Think of it this way... like a paint by numbers game...

But imagine you switched the labels on the paintpots.
Then asked the person... Here is the correct finished painting... now pick the pots to put in the different areas, to match what you see in the finished example.
They would take paint from the paintpots (mislabelled)... and finish the painting.  The paintings would match.  Despite the mislabelled pots... because the wavelength to "seen colour" association is the actuality.
Consider the very specific shades of some colours that get trademarked...

If you can pick "UPS Brown" out of a crowd of colours, you are picking their trademark EM-frequencies out of a crowd of colours.  You are "seeing UPS Brown"...
Recognizing UPS Brown.
Your "UPS Brown" is the same as my UPS Brown, and is the same as the whole world's "UPS Brown"... if they are able to see it and pick it out from among other colours.
The colour itself is primary... the labelling of that colour is secondary and is done by learned association.
We all learned the same labels... to apply to the wavelengths we see.
My "rose" is not your "tulip"... why?  Because we both agreed to use the same dictionary.
Colour labels work that way.  Flower first... label second.

Now, red, on the other hand, is more complex. There are about 15 genes for red perception on the X chromosome, so women get a set from each parent and women rarely have red-green colorblindness and they often can see far more shades of red than most men. I see more reds than most anyone else I know, and they find that very annoying.

@ScottRowe yes.  and all objective.  we CAN show "what Scott Rowe" sees... by showing the "reds" that you can discern between beside one another.  You see "two halves"... others see it all as "one contiguous colour".  Then by showing others a pair they can discern between, we can show them "the nature of" your unique perception... minor discernment between more specific wavelength (or combination of wavelengths??)    It matches that we "perceive" by naming what we objectively distinguished and get trained to label.  I think.

@ScottRowe I remember the first time I put on what I think are called blue blockers... amber coloured sunglasses...  and seeing a forest we were driving past, and being amazed at how easily the different trees stood out from one another, you could see the individual trees the forest was made of.  a huge difference.

Yeah, blue light can override other colors. When I used to ski I had goggles with changeable lens colors. Very interesting experience.

The funny thing is that no-one looking at this is seeing the wavelength of light that is "yellow". Your screen can't make that wavelength of light. Instead you're seeing a mixture of red, green, and blue that your brain interprets as meaning that it is yellow.

@JackAidley touche! So then the question amounts to: "are we having the same illusory experience?" which is a pretty useless question. Next up: "If a tree falls in the forest and no one is around to hear it..." Might as well ask about non-experiences too.

I think the problem with this answer is that it doesn’t address the main question of whether two people’s as-yet unexplained conscious perception of the same wavelength is in fact the same. Yes we label things with the same labels, barring color blindness, but somehow I “see” green as one experience and yellow as another. Do you experience your green the same as I experience my green? That is the question. I would argue that this perception occurs outside of the physical realm because (I contend) that consciousness exist outside it.

@bob I agree it may seem that way... but consider carefully... we take actual "yellow" and train recognition of that "actuality" to the unknowing brain.  That which is seen... gets labelled "yellow".  And we know therefore... that which in the brain got labelleled "yellow" is that specific wavelength of light.  Not another wavelength, that specific wavelength.  (or range, or combination).  There is instance of variable "sensitivity" or "ability to discern"... but there is no mystery about what is being discerned.  Discernment labelling is done by training brain to label the actuality.

Right but if we didn’t have consciousness then theoretically we could still perfectly label and recognize colors without actually consciously perceiving them as colors. It’s the perception that I’m talking about and that I think OP is talking about not the labeling. Why do I see yellow as looking like yellow? Why doesn’t yellow look like pink? Or something else—some color that doesn’t even exist? The wavelength exists in reality. The “color” arguably doesn’t—arguably it’s a construction of our consciousness that does the perceiving and that’s where the mystery lies.

@bob dogs hear higher pitches, what do those sound like? I asked my dog, but he thinks it is a dumb question and won't answer me. Of course, all his answers sound the same to me anyway... If a computer program does image analysis and marks images as having yellow in them, I wonder what it is actually experiencing? We'll never know, I guess. Next question?

This is the only good answer. In particular, it's the only answer that mentions nanometers. The original questioner made a dire mistake by picking a physical phenomenon which can be measured without any human cells; there's no risk of subjectivity, only the usual quantum quirkiness. I grok the urge to talk about quality and Mary's room, but it's all beside the actual point raised in the question.

We can usually be pretty sure that others will agree when we point to something yellow but not always, such as in the case of the picture of a dress that broke the internet. But in any event, we don't have the ability to describe or paint the yellow that other people see. Yellow is the shared reality.  This is why the Heart Sutra says that colour is emptiness. That said, "You" and "I" are also part of the shared reality. There is no cave, darkness, nor homunculus in the darkness looking at the colour, only the frame of our brow, which is part of the colour and, like the colours in the centre likewise unnameable and empty. People like Dennet denied the colour is there at all because it doesn't make sense, and it doesn't. But for me if I am honest, and it is language and sense that disappears not the empty, forbidden colours.
I can't help thinking that David Sylvian was on about the same colours too.

Yay! Another Nonduality enthusiast.

I get it from Ernst Mach, and Kitato Nishida (who recommended Mach). It all makes sense. Hard problem solved.

So, the real question is: do you have a head? I don't. Makes life much simpler :-)

I think that the guy that does not have a head is Jesus, or Amitabha.

Mach discussed the idea that it is strange that the one thing in the universe we can't see is our own head, and drew a picture showing what he sees, including the curve of his nose and "the frame of his brow". Douglas Harding wrote a great book called, "On Having No Head". You should read it.

I have read Mach and I have that book. Harding at times referred to it as God. It has been called many things, but Tim is not one of them. If I were enlightened I might agree, but I am the worm in the mirror. That is a reference to Doug TenNapel's "Earthworm Jim." Jim's super suit has no helmet.
